# j2me function java.lang.nullpointerexception - what is wrong in this?

Tags: java, java-me, java.lang.class

Yesterday Night, i wrote this function to fetch all the tags from string containing xml data but something is not correct in this... Pls help... this function is returning java.lang.NullPointerException

```
  public void parseWebXML(String xd){
      int i, j, k = 0;
      String tagn, check = "";
      int spos, epos;
      byte[] len = xd.getBytes();
      tags = new String[len.length*3/4];
      int nextpos = 0;
      for(i=0;i<len.length*3/4;i++){
        spos = xd.indexOf("<", nextpos);
        epos = xd.indexOf(">", spos);
        tagn = xd.substring(spos, epos);
        if(i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2){
            if(tagn.indexOf("/") == -1){
                tags[k] = "<"+tagn+">";
                k +=1;
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        }else{
            if(tagn.indexOf("/") == -1){
                for(j=0;j<tags.length;j++){
                    if(tags[i].equals(tags[j])){
                        check = "found";
                    }else{
                        check = "notfound";
                    }
                }
                if(check.equals("notfound")){
                    tags[i] = "<"+tagn+">";
                    k+=1;
                }else{
                    continue;
                }
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        }
        nextpos = epos + 1;
      }
  }
```

error that i saw while executing in debugger mode

```
TRACE: <at java.lang.NullPointerException:   0>, Exception caught in Display class
java.lang.NullPointerException:   0
 - httpcon.parseWebXML(), bci=170
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialized tags[], but not each of its cells, so `tags[i].equals(tags[j])` probably caused the `NPE` (`tags[i]` is null).

Comment: thanks man... your answer helped me in detecting problem in another funtion in series... In present one... bug was different.

Answer (score 1):

tags[] has only 3 items.

```
if(i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2){
            if(tagn.indexOf("/") == -1){
                tags[k] = "<"+tagn+">";
                k +=1;
```

if i > 3 than tags[i] return null. And tags[i].equals throw NPE